# What's benefit of docker's image layer?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker. Based on reading some Docker documentation, I plan to convert my project to Docker image as the following design:

My project has the follow natures:

- The base OS almost never need to update unless big OS issue, thus say update base OS every 2 years.
- The base libraries might be updated only 6 months.
- Libraries are updated every month.
- Project code are updated once a day.

Thus I plan to create 4 images:

- image1 - base os
- image2 - from image1 and add base libraries
- image3 - from image2 and add libraries
- image4 - from image3 and add project code

My understanding is, image4 has 4 layers. Once I build a new image4, Docker only needs to pull layer4, because layer 1,2,3 are same as the old image4. Since my project code is just some text scripts, thus layer4 should be very small, thus pull a new image4 should be very fast.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since my project code is just some text scripts, thus layer4 should be very small

Layer4 will be small, but pulling image4 will be fast only if one has already pulled image 1 to 3 before.

And the resulting image4 won't be small, but the result of the concatenation of the 3 base images.

Plus, the term "layer" should not mask the fact that each line in a docker file will create an intermediate image, making the actual image a collection of all those intermediate small layers (resulting from the execution of each Dockerfile command).
You might have 4 "general" layers, but the actual image is  likely to be composed of more than 4 layers.
You can check that with [**imagelayers.io**](https://imagelayers.io/)

I use an [alias to cleanup old dangling images](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/ece7836c7538456c735f9a46b1bf273db82697ac/.bash_aliases#L22):

```
alias drmiad='docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)'
```

My [build script](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/96069b19f298763937f472ca7e81df125aaa9870/sshd/build#L4-L7) usually include:

```
. ../.bash_aliases

docker build -t sshd . || exit 1
drmiad 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: When I first pull image4, will image1/2/3 will auto pulled? since image4 is from image1/2/3.

Comment: @EvanLi yes, 1,2, 3 will be pulled as well. AS to my last point, even ubuntu itself has 4 layers: https://imagelayers.io/?images=ubuntu:latest

Comment: Actually I don't mind how many layers the image in fact has, what I want to archive is, pulling a new image4 is very fast. So my design should archive my goal, is that correct?

Comment: @TieDad yes, your design is correct. You should always start from the more generic stable layer to the more specific one.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. The follow up question is, if one day I update image3 to image3.1, and rebuild a new image4.1 based on image3.1. Since old image3/4 will no longer be used, should I manually clean up the old image3/4? Or is there any automatic mechanism  to clean up dead images?

Comment: Yes, I do that all the time: image cleanup: https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/ece7836c7538456c735f9a46b1bf273db82697ac/.bash_aliases#L22: `alias drmiad='docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)'`. I just type `drmiad` after each of my build script: https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/96069b19f298763937f472ca7e81df125aaa9870/sshd/build#L4-L7